# OleDbCommand with bind variables

Tags: c#, database, oracle, oledbcommand

I am trying to use bind variables with a OleDbCommand. I have the following code

```
    var SQL = @"select * from table where order_no = '@ORDER_NO'";
    using (var cmd = new OleDbCommand(SQL, connection))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@ORDER_NO", "1234"));
        using (var dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                // do something
            }
        }
    }
```

When I run this code nothing is returned from the database. If I change the SQL to be

```
var SQL = @"select * from table where order_no = '1234'";
```

A result is returned. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you are using Oracle database, consider download the [.Net Oracle Provider](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/index-085163.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the apostrophes around `@ORDER_NO`:

```
var SQL = @"select * from table where order_no = @ORDER_NO";
```

Otherwise it's not a parameter but a string literal and you're looking for a `order_no` = `@ORDER_NO`.